# Get Boolean Value from Reddit .JSON Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, reddit

The file can be viewed [here](http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/25dae11d). I am parsing for the attribute "likes" but I am getting `<null>` even when I have liked the post. I am 100% sure my modhash is valid, and when I view the file I can see that true is appearing for posts I have upvoted.

My Code:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://reddit.com/.json"]];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSArray *objects = [[json objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"children"];



postArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int likesCnt = 0;
for (NSDictionary *object in objects) {
    NSObject *likeObj = [[object objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"likes"] ;
    NSObject *data = [object objectForKey:@"data"];  

    int voteDirection = 0;
    if(![likeObj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && [[data valueForKey:@"likes"] boolValue])
        voteDirection = 1;
    else if(![likeObj isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && ![[data valueForKey:@"likes"] boolValue])
        voteDirection = -1;


    //Reddit Post in an NSObject Class for organizing info for specific posts.
    RedditPost *post = postArr[likesCnt];
    post.currentVote = voteDirection;
    postArr[likesCnt] = post;
    NSLog(@"Title:(%@) Vote:(%d)",post.title,voteDirection);
    likesCnt++;
}
```

New file: http://www1.datafilehost.com/d/25dae11d

Comment: "I am getting (?) even"... I think you may be missing a word there?  (Or maybe you literally are getting even)?  Welcome to SO

Comment: Forgot to put the Code Attributes, thanks.

Comment: "but I am getting <null> even when I have liked the post" . Well in your file all values for key "likes" are null...

Comment: I think the problem is simply that you aren't telling us what is really happening with your program. The information your provided are inconsistent, it just can't be that a comparison between *[likeObj class]* and *[NSNull null]* returns true, as they're different classes. When you post a question you should carefully provide all the information, otherwise answers biased on wrong information are useless.